# How to update windows 7 with one program?

Tags: windows-7, updates

I reinstalled windows 7 but I don't want to spend time for all windows updates and program and driver updates. Is there any program that updates windows and all programs with one click?

Answer (score 2):

all programmes? no

I tend to use a two or three tier method - [wsus offline update](http://download.wsusoffline.net/) for windows and office patching. [ninite for initial software install](http://ninite.com/) where supported. Together, these ensure i have the most recent version of the software i use, and everything is patched up quickly.

Comment: Dude... I like this Ninite thing. I've never heard of it before, but it looks like everything Google Pack tried to be.

Answer (score 1):

If there was, many help desk level jobs would be a heck of a lot easier.

For an entire network, you can so something like WSUS, Shavlik, and/or SMS. For an individual computer, there isn't much. Just set everything to do it automatically. For the big 4 (Windows, AV, Adobe, Java) this should be fairly easy and have a minimal amount of interaction necessary.